# TWS (trader work station) Interactive broker - no sound

Tags: sound

I am using build 981.2 TWS from interactive brokers. I can't figure out how to deal with following error message:

> Audio playback is not supported by your system

I am working with Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. Sound is working just fine. Somehow TWS is asking for an older library.
Anyone?

Comment: I have the same problem. Following.

Comment: Menubar > Edit > Global Configuration > Sound Manager. Then point to a .wav formatted file for each sound you want to hear. Tedious, but works.

Answer (score 3):

You will need to install all the media codecs using the command given below.
Once the screen to accept the agreement appears just press Tab and then enter to install. Should work just fine after that.`sudo add-apt-repository multiverse`

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

Answer (score 1):

A [workaround found](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=47&p=2100760&t=362137) is to convert the mp3 files to wav (they are found in `(...)Jts/randomString/sounds/en` and then setting the wav as the sound in `File-Global Configuration - Configuration - Sound manager`

Answer (score 1):

This applies to making the sound work on alerts. 1st of all I'm using Trader Work Station not Mosaic. To create an alert I right click on the line, and then click on the bell icon, then create new alert. When you create an alert, at the bottom of the box you should see, "Advanced Settings" click on it. 2 boxes should open, click on cancel in the smaller one. Now in the box that remains, in the middle, you should see 3 tabs labeled "Orders, Messages,Audio" click on Audio, then just below select Custom, then browse. I put a .wav file in the first folder that appears and I named it 00.wav so it would be the first file to appear and spare me the extra clicks and scrolling to get TWS sounds folder. Let me know if that works. BTW you have to do this every time you create an alert. I haven't figured to make this a default, yet.
1